# Force controller to use current_user with mocking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, stub, mocha.js

I am trying to specify in my RSpec tests that my controller should use `current_user.projects.find()` instead of `Project.find()` I am using the Mocha mocking framework and was trying something like this:

```
controller.current_user.projects.expects(:find).returns(@project)
```

I have already mocked out `controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@profile)`

This test passes with this even when I use the `Project.find()` implementation. How can I test that my controller is calling off of the correct object?

Edit (adding additional code):

I have Projects and Tasks, Project have many tasks. This is the show method for displaying a task in a project that is owned by `current_user`

Action in the controller:

```
def show
    @project = current_user.projects.find_by_id(params[:cardset_id])

    if @project.nil?
      flash[:notice] = "That project doesn't exist. Try again."
      redirect_to(projects_path)
    else
      @task = @project.tasks.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

This is the test that is not checking that the `cardsets` method was called off the `current_user` object.

Current Test:

```
context "with get to show" do
  context "with valid project" do
    before(:each) do
      @project = Factory(:project)
      @task = Factory(:task)
      @profile = @project.profile
      ApplicationController.stubs(:require_user).returns(true)
      controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(@profile)

      Project.stubs(:find_by_id).returns(@project)
      @project.tasks.stubs(:find_by_id).returns(@task)
      get :show, :project_id => @project.id, :id => @task.id
    end

    it "should assign task" do
      assigns[:task].should_not be_nil
    end

    it "should assign project" do
      assigns[:project].should_not be_nil
    end
  end

  context "with invalid project" do
    before(:each) do
      Project.stubs(:find_by_id).returns(nil)
      get :show, :project_id => @project.id, :id => @task.id
    end

    it "should set flash" do
      flash[:notice].should match(/doesn't exist/i)
    end

    it "should redirect" do
      response.should redirect_to(cardsets_url)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: giving more of the code from both the test and the controller could help. its unclear how a test could be passing if the expectation is clearly not met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the little you've told us, I think you need:

```
@profile.expects(:find).returns(@project)
```

Comment: This is close to what I needed.... `@profile.cardsets.expects(:find_by_id).returns(@project)`